# numpy.where does not filter points == 0 out

Tags: python, numpy, divide-by-zero

using numpy.where() to filter out cases where the input array element is == 0 in order to avoid divisin by 0 does not work.

using a simple for loop everything is fine, but using np.where() the RuntimeWarning appears. I tried explicitly defining the array dtype but the warning still appears. Why is this the case?

```py
# test array
x = np.array([1e-20, 1, 10, 0], dtype=np.float64)

# divide by x except where x == 0 
np.where(x == 0, 1/np.pi, np.sin(x)/(np.pi*x))
# returns correct values but with RuntimeWarning 

# for loop works with no warnings appearing
for x_i in x:
    if x_i == 0:
        print(1/np.pi)
    else:
        print(np.sin(x_i)/(np.pi*x_i))
```

Comment: This is slightly different from that question, as you want to return 1/pi instead of 0, but you can fix that by changing the code to replace `np.zeros_like(a)` with an array filled with 1/pi.

Comment: Hi Nick, thnx for the answer! its definitely a workaround but I'm curious why np.where does not work here... I don't really see the mistake

Comment: `np.where` just selects between two arrays **after those were computed**, so **after** the warning already occurred.

Comment: It's too late by the time you call `numpy.where`, the arguments are fully evaluated

Comment: `np.where` is a python function.  The arguments are arrays, not functions. It's the python evaluation order that matters here.